# What's the best way of making single app with different logic depending on the user's role?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Let's say we have two user roles:

1. Reader
2. Writer

Now i need to allow users to create posts with role `writer`. `Reader` role can only read and mark it's read. They have same entry point with almost same logic. But how do i can differentiate logic based on user role?

I think creating one more activity will lead in code duplication. But also usage of `if/else` will make it complicated

What is the best practice to handle different user role in single app?

Comment: This might be a good question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, I would suggest to make another Activity.

Using if/else logic all over the place does make your code more messy and complicated. It also causes your code to be more troublesome and difficult to make changes to in the future, for example... if you suddenly had to introduce a new role like 'Editor'. It would be silly to go through all your code and modify the if/else logic for all affected methods to include the new role.

It's better to just create a new Activity. However, this doesn't mean there would be code duplication. Keep in mind 'Writer' and 'Reader' actually shares a lot of code.

I don't know the specifics for you, but I assume that 'Writer' has all the capabilities of a 'Reader', but more.

So you can create an Activity for 'Reader', then extend that Activity for 'Writer' and include only 'Writer' specific code in this WriterActivity.

Or you're always free to create a base Activity with only the common features of 'Writer' and 'Reader', then create a ReaderActivity or WriterActivity that extends from that base.

Basically, I suggest using another Activity and you shouldn't be concerned about having an extra Activity leading to code duplication. This is mainly because part of the reason for the concept of inheritance in Java is to avoid code duplication and reduce redundancy.